# Make select2.js and default select work in the first row of a dynamically generated row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have two fields in a dynamically generated row. One is a `select2` select box another one default `select` input field. With my current code, both the select options can be selected in the child rows, but in the parent row, when select2 becomes working, default select options could not be selected.

My Script is:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.item1', function() {
    var select2_open;
    $(this).select2().select2('open');
});
```

This script helped me to show the select2 fields options in the child rows.

My view is:

[image: an error]

Html view is:

```
<div class="span2">
    <label style="font-size:13px;">Labour Code</label>
    <select type="text" id="labour_code locationCodesParent" class="item1"  name="lc[]" onChange="UpdateInfo(<?php echo $k=1;?>);" style="width:100px;" />
        <option value=""></option>
        <?php
            foreach($labour as $row)
            {?>
                <option value ="<?php echo $row['labour_code']; ?>"><?php echo $row['labour_code']; ?></option>
            <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

The script side code is:

```
var html="<div class='span2 pdfs locationCodesParent' style='margin-left:0px;'><select class='labour_code2 item1'  name='lc[]'  style='width:100px;' onChange='UpdateInfo1(this.value,"+count+");'><option value=''></option> <?php foreach($labour as $row) { ?> <option value='<?php echo $row['labour_code']; ?>'><?php echo $row['labour_code']; ?></option> <?php } ?></select></div>"; 

$("#rezult").append(html);
```

Select2.js and select2.min.css files are included in the footer and header respectively. The Js fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/dytfcmLd/

Comment: Default select not working means what you are facing exactly?

Comment: When I make Select2 dropdown working, the second select (which I have circled in the image) dropdown does not work ..

Comment: Is it not clickable or something else?

Comment: Even if its clicked no dropdown is viewed..its like an inactive button

Comment: try to set width of select2 dropdown as 100% i.e `$(this).select2({ width:'100%' })`

Comment: When I make the select list working, select2 fails to work, and this is the error I get in the console [error] Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null ...in the console.